# How to call a stored procedure using an wildcard for the Integer parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

There is a public stored procedure that takes a customer ID and returns that customer's order info. The customer ID as a single integer parameter. I would like to be able to run it and pull all orders for all customers but I cannot modify the stored procedure.

Is there a wildcard that I could send as the Customer ID that will trick the stored procedure to return all existing customer orders?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a SQL injection attempt.

Comment: Ask the author of the stored procedure  - only he knows whether or not there's a "mechanism" built-in to ignore the `CustomerID` and return all data ....

Comment: No. Only character data types have wildcards in sql.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass NULL for the parameter and adjust the stored proc to handle that appropriately:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomerOrders 
(
    @CustomerId int = NULL
) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM CustomerOrders 
    WHERE @CustomerId IS NULL OR CustomerId = @CustomerId
END
```

Then you can do:

```
exec GetCustomerOrders
```

or

```
exec GetCustomerOrders @CustomerId
```

Comment: I forgot to mention. I can't modify the store procedure.

Comment: sorry, no wildcards then... in a way this is one of the reasons to use stored procs, so people don't send arbitrary queries to the db.